# Convert powershell table to json with column 1 as key and column 2 as value

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to produce a JSON dictionary from a powershell object with formatting that the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet doesn't provide by default.

For example the `ConvertTo-Json` will take the output of

```
(get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | select InstanceName, CookedValue
```

which looks like:

```
InstanceName        CookedValue
------------        -----------
idle             92.02923730929
process1                      3
process2                      1
process3                      0
process4                      2
process5                      0
process6                      2
process7                      0
....                       ....
```

and produce a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "InstanceName":  "idle",
    "CookedValue":  92.02923730929
},
{
    "InstanceName":  "process1",
    "CookedValue":  3
},
{
    "InstanceName":  "process2",
    "CookedValue":  1
},
...
]
```

Would it be possible to instead format the JSON object like this?:

```
{
    idle: 92.02923730929,
    process1: 3,
    process2: 1,
    process3: 0,
    process4: 2,
    process5: 0,
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new object with properties made up of the sample property values:

```
$properties = @{}
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples |ForEach-Object {
    $properties[$_.InstanceName] = $_.CookedValue
}
New-Object psobject -Properties $properties |ConvertTo-Json
```

Since you could have multiple instances with the same process name, you might want to extract the process name and instance number from the counter `Path` instead:

```
$properties = @{}
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples |ForEach-Object {
    $InstanceName = if($_.Path -match 'process\((.*#\d+)\)'){
        $Matches[1]
    } 
    else {
        $_.InstanceName
    }
    $properties[$InstanceName] = $_.CookedValue
}
New-Object psobject -Property $properties |ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just pipe it to `ConvertTo-Json`

```
(get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | select InstanceName, CookedValue | ConvertTo-Json
```

I cannot answer your second question of reformatting the JSON output